# React Router and Link do not render

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, render

I'm working on a react app and I found my page does not render when the url changes. See the code below, I have a navigagtion bar with three `Link`, when I click them, I can see that the url changes in the address bar, but the page is still staying the one from the old url. However if I refresh the page, then the corresponding page to the current url is rendered and presented.

I saw a similar question but the method in it does not work for me, or maybe I use it in a wrong way? [React Router or Link Not Rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47088770/react-router-or-link-not-rendered)

this is the code from my `App.js`:

```
import {BrowserRouter, Switch, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './booking/Home';
import Login from './auth/Login';
import Register from './auth/Register';

const TopNav = () => (
  <div className="nav bg-light d-flex justify-content-between">
    <Link className="nav-link" to="/">
      Home
    </Link>
    <Link className="nav-link" to="/login">
      Login
    </Link>
    <Link className="nav-link" to="/register">
      Register
    </Link>
  </div>
);


function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      {TopNav()}
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

What is your React Router version? If it's React Router v6. You need to change it like this below:

```
<Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
<Route exact path="/login" element={<Login />} />
<Route exact path="/register" element={<Register />} />
```

Because using `component` is from React Router v5, the newest version using `element`

Hope it helps!

Comment: I agree, but I also think that the links/routes shouldn't be placed in a function that returns them, I think the call {TopNav()} will not work by design

Comment: @ferrouskid I already tested, but it's actually works just by using {TopNav()}

Comment: oh ok, thanks for the response! I'll know for the future :)

Comment: @typeocen Hi my ```react-router-dom``` is version 5.2.0, so I don't think its the reason. I tried to change  component to element but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to use JSX for your TopNav component?

```
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <TopNav/>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Also put react in scope for your app at the top

```
import React from 'react';
```

```
import {BrowserRouter, Switch, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './Home';
import Login from './Login';
import Register from './Register';
import React from 'react';

const TopNav = () => (
  <div className="nav bg-light d-flex justify-content-between">
    <Link className="nav-link" to="/">
      Home
    </Link>
    <Link className="nav-link" to="/login">
      Login
    </Link>
    <Link className="nav-link" to="/register">
      Register
    </Link>
  </div>
);


function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter forceRefresh>
      <TopNav />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Hi @CodeoftheWarrior it does not work for me.

Comment: You forgot to import React from 'react'; at the top of your file.

Comment: Put the whole file that works for me up above.

Comment: I did it still does not work, but thank you :)